# updating multiple rows with JOIN statement in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. (in MySQL)

Table 'categoryimport' contains category name in local language.

```
ID        Category      ID_category
1000001     Autoservisy   NULL
1000002     Autoservisy   NULL
1000002     Pneuservisy   NULL
1000003     Autoservisy   NULL
1000004     Autoservisy   NULL
1000005     Autoservisy   NULL
```

Table 'categorylang' also contains the same category name in local language wit their ID (ID_category field).

```
ID_category      EN                       CZ
100              Garages              Autoservisy
101              Car bodywork             Autoklempíři
102              Motor-vehicle electrics  Autoelektrikáři
103              Car Dealers              Auto-moto prodejci 
110              Windscreen repair    Opravy autoskel
111              Tire service             Pneuservisy
```

All I need to do is insert ID_category from 'categorylang' Table into their corresponding ID_category in Table 'categoryimport' based on categoryimport.Category = categorylang.CZ
I tried with:

```
UPDATE categoryimport JOIN categorylang 
ON categoryimport.Category = categorylang.CZ SET categoryimport.ID_category = categorylang.ID_category
```

The result is:

```
ID        Category      ID_category
1000001     Autoservisy   100
1000002     Autoservisy   **NULL**
1000002     Pneuservisy   111
1000003     Autoservisy   100
1000004     Autoservisy   100
1000005     Autoservisy   100
```

Field ID-category for 1000002 is not updated. Has to be updated as well with 100 value. Only one value of 1000002 is updated.

I need a following result:

```
ID        Category      ID_category
1000001     Autoservisy   100
1000002     Autoservisy   **100**
1000002     Pneuservisy   111
1000003     Autoservisy   100
1000004     Autoservisy   100
1000005     Autoservisy   100
```

With CURSORS will be possible to solve the issue but I prefer some simple SQL statement. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe trim Category column a space might be at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to work fine, see this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f521f/2

It could be that there are spaces in some records of the imported table, 
look at this record in the demo:

```
(9999999, ' Autoservisy', NULL)
```

- this record has not been updated by the query.